# Referring to related object instance

Tags: django

I have list of people on the group detail page. I'm trying to remove person from group and redirect page back to that group.

```
from .models import Person, Group

def person_remove(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Person, slug=slug)
    instance.delete()

    the_group = ?
    group_slug = ?
    return redirect('group_detail', slug=group_slug)
```

As you can see I'm passing 'slug' parameter from Person object, but I'm trying to redirect to that Group detail page which contains that person.

## Edit

Ok it looks like this:

Group list, url based on slug:

```
url(r'^group/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', GroupDetailView.as_view() , name='group_detail')
```

1. Group A
2. Group B

Ok, enter Group A represents with group-a slug. On that page we have:
List of persons related to that group. Every person has his own slug:

```
url(r'^person/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PersonDetailView.as_view() , name='person_detail')
```

- person 1
- person 2
- person 3

I created instance method function in person model:

```
def person_remove(self):
    return reverse('person_delete', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug})
```

Which refers to :

```
url(r'^person/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', person_delete , name='person_delete'),
```

And lastly it refers to function I wrote at the beginning. I'm trying to find a solution how to redirect back to that url where I clicked 'delete person'

Answer (score 0):

what you mentioned does not remove Person instance from a group, but deletes Person instance.
Based on your model you need to do something like this:

```
peter = get_object_or_404(Person, slug=slug)
group = Group.objects.get(slug="Some group slug")
peter.group_set.remove(group)
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)